# How to enter password on asyncssh.run("sudo su") and continue to input commands?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ssh, python-asyncio

In the python 3 script I need to enter a few commands under root priveleges via asyncssh.

Something like this code sample:

```
async with asyncssh.connect(host=IP, port=PORT, username=ORDINARY_USER, password=PASSWORD, known_hosts=None) as conn:
    result_su = await conn.run('echo "verysecretpass" | su', check=False)
    result_1 = await conn.run("root_command1", check=False)
    print(result_1.stdout)
    result_2 = await conn.run("root_command2", check=False)
    print(result_2.stdout)
```

This sample is not working of course. What changes are needed to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `su` you may use `sudo` with the `-S` switch which reads the password from STDIN:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

Credits to [sudo with password in one command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/67765/).